# Free and paid data stored in database(s)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to implement a free and paid database version in my android app. In my app I am trying to display Points of Interest (POI) which are stored in a sqlite db.

My scenario is that in the Free version my sqlite will contain 10 POI entries. When a user purchases the premium version from Google Play, another 100 POI entries must be added to the original sqlite. What is the best way to do this?

Do I need to provide all the paid and unpaid database entries in my free version only? Can i have the unpaid and paid entries seperately and when the user purchases merge them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two scenarios:

1. You have two versions of your app in the store (paid and free). The free version has limited content and solicits the user to go to the store to buy the full version. In this case, you can define two flavors in your Gradle build script (see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) and each flavor can provide it's own assets.
2. Your app is free and offers in-app purchases (a premium upgrade). In this case you can either store the full content in the app's assets but limit the access to them until the user purchases the upgrade. Or you can have the full content downloadable from your web service after the purchase is authenticated.

Comment: Interesting, however if I have the full version of sqlite on the free version it can be easily hacked. The web service approach is more appropriate I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new column as flag to mark the POI to be or not to be shown on the application, and mark all as visible when the user pays.